# wpml multilingual cms plugin problem (wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress, multilingual

I have installed the wpml multilingual cms plugin in my wordpress site.
The problem is when i try posting or editing a post there is no success message. The page just get stucks on post.php showing a blank page.When i go back to previous page the new post is added and in case of edit the post is updated. But my problem is while submitting the post it shows a blank page. Please help

Thanks,
Raul

Answer (score 0):

The blank page usually means a fatal error occurred, but error reporting is set not to display it. Check your server's Apache & PHP error logs.

Comment: Thanks Dan, I just checked my error log but there is no error related to it. :( I am trying to debug it and i found that edit_post() function is not returning any value on post page.