# WPML blank page on submit in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wpml

This question is related to [wpml multilingual cms plugin problem (wordpress)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4385762/wpml-multilingual-cms-plugin-problem-wordpress) where no solution has been found.

I have WPML 3.1.5 and Wordpress 3.9.1, and whenever I activate the plugin, every submit action (posting, saving, changing settings) is met with the blank post.php page.

Because of this, the login/logout and registration doesn't work.

Wordpress gives no error logs, Apache's own error log is empty.

It's driving me up the walls. Does anyone know what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because there is a plugin/theme with is having incompatibility. If you do not know which plugin/theme is, the best way is:
1 go to you ftp server and rename the folder /wp-content/plugins to another name
2 load wp-admin.php an go to plugin, It will show you an error message and all plugins will be disabled 
3 rename back the folder to the original name /wp-content/plugins.
4 go to plugins option in wp-admin and active one by one until find which one is wrong.
5 99% the problem is because of the plugin, if it is not, try to do it with themes.

Once you get what plugin/theme is doing wrong, try to update or check if there is any error. You can debug your website enabling WP_DEBUG in wp-config.php file from you root folder.

define('WP_DEBUG', true); // false

if (WP_DEBUG) {

define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);

define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true);

I think the last verion of WPML is 3.1.6 . There is the link to download it to update http://ul.to/qjl85490